# Defining Singleton vs declaring in interface

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I wanted to know is it an good idea to define my factory object in an interface or make an singleton factory for it.

Scenario:
I have multiple factories which I want to have single instances, so should I create an singleton factory or should declaring then in an interface is also ok

I am building an api for other teams so can't use spring or guice.

Comment: Why not just use a static factory method?

Comment: How does the difference matter? Assuming the interface is related to instances being created, it's a matter of preference.

Comment: Are you sure you need to make the factory singleton? There are reasons it might (shared state, expensive to create etc); but in many cases it needn't be.

Comment: Seriously though, a factory that keeps state sounds like a bad design to me.

Comment: @Jai agreed. But more broadly, singleton is often worth avoiding.